# Unity mudar a ordem de um game object via código por C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Bom eu tenho um Game Object chamado Party Frames.

Dentro dele eu tenho vários prefabs com nomes diferentes (seus nomes são os IDs dos personagens) e são UIs de rostos de personagens.

A única coisa que eu quero é mudar a ordem destes objetos de nomes diferentes via código pois quando eu mudo a ordem da prefab ele muda a posição automaticamente da UI e preciso fazer um esquema de ordem onde eu posiciono as UI do jeito que eu quiser. Pois dependendo da velocidade do personagem a UI vem primeiro, e depois que passa o turno do personagem ele vai para o final da fila.

Não sei se fui claro, qualquer dúvida é só falar.

No caso a ordem que eu quero alterar são os 1(clone), 2(clone), etc.

Eu pesquisei e falaram para usar a função GetSiblingIndex, porém eu não sei como usar no meu código. Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É bastante fácil. Eis um exemplo de código, que coloca o item "9(Clone)" antes do item "7(Clone)":

```
Transform pf = GameObject.Find("Party Frames").transform;
Transform c9 = pf.Find("9(Clone)");
c9.SetSiblingIndex(1);
```

A primeira linha obtém o objeto `Transform` do objeto pai (e não seria necessária se você estiver executando o código diretamente num script anexado a esse objeto, pois você poderia utilizar diretamente `transform`). A segunda linha obtém o objeto a ter a posição alterada na hierarquia dentre os "irmãos" (*siblings* em inglês). A terceira linha faz o que vc quer, isto é, muda a posição desse objeto obtido na linha acima.

Observe que:

1. O método `GetSiblingIndex` apenas te devolve o índice do objeto dentre seus irmãos. Pode ser útil em algum caso que você não especificou, mas pra mudar basta alterar indicando a posição desejada no método [`SetSiblingIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html).
2. As posições são contadas a partir de 0, de forma que a primeira posição é 0, a segunda é 1, a terceira é 2, e assim por diante. Como, no exemplo, eu queria colocar o item "9(Clone)" (que era o 4º) antes do "7(Clone)" (que era o 2º), bastou colocar o objeto no índice 1 (lembra? 0 é o primeiro, 1 é o segundo...). A Unity automaticamente "empurra" os demais pra frente, colocando o objeto na posição que você solicitou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

P.S.: Como [você mesmo percebeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244000/unity-mudar-a-ordem-de-um-game-object-via-c%c3%b3digo-por-c/244452?noredirect=1#comment501105_244452), existe também o método [`SetAsLastSibling`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsLastSibling.html) que coloca o item diretamente como último. A vantagem dele é que você não precisa saber o índice do último elemento (equivalente à quantidade de elementos - 1).

Comment: Muito bom funcionou e usei também, o SetAsLastSibling(); Acho bom por na resposta também.